# A clik for idenfied element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was looking on internet if it's possible by a click to identified an element by a click. For exemple if i click on a text, an alert come say it's a text. For an text field that's will be alert with text field, for a button : alert button, etc

But i dont find on internet, and i don't know how i can make it, if someone can tell me if it's possible or not.

I already do a click for identified for where is the mouse (x and y) :

```
function ejs_context_position(e)
    {
    ejs_context_x = (navigator.appName.substring(0,3) == "Net") ? e.pageX : event.x+document.body.scrollLeft;
    ejs_context_y = (navigator.appName.substring(0,3) == "Net") ? e.pageY : event.y+document.body.scrollTop;
}
```

But i can't find how to do it for an element

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to an elements tag name using the **[element].tagName** property. See the resource below for information on implementation - it should be relatively straightforward to define a function which takes an element as input and returns the elements tagName.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_tagname.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event listener on every element on your page

```
element.addEventListener("click", printElement(null, element))
// OR
<div class="div" onclick="printElement('div')">
```

Then use the class you assigned to that element to know which kind of element it is.

```
function printElement(class, element) {
  if (class) return console.log('Element clicked is: ' + class);
  // Get the class from the element
  console.log('Element clicked is: ' + element.className);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To identify an element by a click event, you need to register a event listener to that element, and when the event is triggered, the event will carry the target DOM element.

In the following example, we can access tha tag name of the target DOM element.

If you want to listen to a click event in all elements inside body, you could add the listener to the body as follow:

- Note: After running the following code, try clicking on the page elements and see the result.

```js
window.onclick = function(event) {
  alert(event.target.tagName);
  console.log(event.target.tagName);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>HTML Forms</h2>

  <form action="/action_page.php">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
    <br> Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <p>description text in the tag p</p>

</body>

</html>
```